# What is the function of "o"?

Tags: words, honorifics, prefixes, bikago

Why do people have to add "o" to "namae" like "Onamae wa?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お and ご are prefixes used to make a word sound more respectful/polite.

お prefixes words with kunyomi readings such as:

- お客さん
- お手洗い
- お茶

ご prefixes words with onyomi readings such as:

- ご飯
- ご利用
- ご注文

Comment: But namae is kun reading, isn't it?

Comment: My bad, I mixed up the names.

Comment: It should be noted that there are exceptions, like 「お茶{ちゃ}」「お誕生日{たんじょうび}」「ごもっとも」「ごゆっくり」.

Comment: Looking more closely at your answer, I see you've listed お客さん and お茶, but きゃく and ちゃ are on'yomi, not kun'yomi.